# Who wanted to kill the Hulk?

Tags: comics, marvel, the-incredible-hulk

Towards the end of World War Hulk, Miek implies someone wanted to kill off the hulk, as he had averted the slaughter of the indigenous peoples (something Meik seems to believe is inevitable, and thus must happen).

Meik himself didn't load the Warp Core but he didn't stop them as he knew what would happen.

*Who did load the warp core that killed Caiera and destroyed the planet?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loyalists to Angmo-Asan, The Red King of Sakaar, replaced the warp core on the Hulk's ship in an effort to assassinate him. While Hulk's ship was being turned into a monument to his defeat of of the tyrant, it detonated, destroying the capital city.